# MongoDB YAML "Unrecognized option: security"

Tags: mongodb, yaml

I am running Mongo DB version 2.6 on Windows Server 2012.  I am having trouble setting up the YAML config file for for security and authorization.  When I have the below config file I only receive an error saying "Unrecognized option: security".  What is wrong with my config?

**mongod_test.conf:**

```
security:
    authorization: enabled
    authenticationMechanisms: MONGODB-CR
storage:
   dbPath: F:\MongoData
```

**Command line:**

```
mongod.exe --config mongod_test.conf
```

I've added spaces back to my file and that fixes part of the problem.  With the updated config from above the current error I am getting is:

```
c:\MongoDBFolder\bin>mongod.exe --config mongod_test.conf
    Unrecognized option: security.authenticationMechanisms
    try 'mongod.exe --help' for more information
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Can't speak for your exact config, but Yaml requires colon+space to separate the keys and values, otherwise you'll get parse errors;

```
security:
    authorization: enabled
    authenticationMechanisms: MONGODB-CR
storage:
   dbPath: F:\MongoData
```

Comment: as described in another answer, it is not possible to specifiy "authenticationMechanisms" inside "security": http://stackoverflow.com/a/29354466/198996

Comment: Yep. My issue was resolved with this.

Answer (score 3):

The error:

```
Unrecognized option: security.authenticationMechanisms
```

is because authenticationMechanisms is not part of the "security" configuration.

As per the documentation: 
 http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#security

However, authenticationMechanisms is an option for "setParameter", as per this documentation:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/parameters/#param.authenticationMechanisms

I find the documentation convoluted and confusing, but I've not found anything to contradict this, yet.

So, given the above, I think you should be looking at the following:

```
security:
   authorization: enabled
setParameter:
   authenticationMechanisms: MONGODB-CR    
storage:
  dbPath: "F:\MongoData"
```

Comment: i think this only works if your database is empty at the time you start the server with this configuration. otherwise you have to follow these steps: http://drorasaf.blogspot.co.at/2015/10/the-mongodb-use-authentication-incident.html or https://scalegrid.io/blog/configuring-mongodb-cr-authentication-as-default-on-mongodb-3-x/

Answer (score 2):

Can you ensure there is a space after ":" for the key-value pair lines and also enclose the string values like dbPath value in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

I had an extremely similar error when trying to setup SSL, searching for my problem this was the only relevant result, but was not the solution that was required.

I had a problem with the error:

> "Unrecognized option: net.ssl.mode"

The issue was the mongodb version. I had installed using brew which does not default to mongodb with ssl support. To fix this the I had to use the `--with-openssl` flag.

```
brew install mongodb --with-openssl
```

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure your header isn't commented out
`security` not `#security`

Comment: My scenario was the same. I edited the default file where security was COMMENTED. So uncommenting it helped the server to start running.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the configuration file uses ASCII encoding. mongod does not support configuration files with non-ASCII encoding, including UTF-8.